# Playbook linting

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

I want to lint a playbook to detect following few among many other possibilities:

1. Undefined variable
2. Unused variable
3. See if vars defined, when case-ignored, are same( conflicting vars hereafter)

I'm not able to figure out what is the good way to do this? I don't want to re-invent the wheel, in the sense that:

1. I don't want to do text processing. Ansible does this to accomplish its task.
2. Hooks or callbacks if I'm not wrong are couple of levels higher than where I think my solution should hop in.

My intention is to write a tool that seamlessly, and optionally, works with ansible. I would like not to modify ansible's code if I can do without.

Any help or hack or suggestion is appreciated.

PS: Syntax check wouldn't tell me about what I have mentioned above.
I've taken a look at the [ansible-lint](https://github.com/willthames/ansible-lint) tool. It does text processing, doesn't support inventory(for host_vars etc) and doesn't use ansible python API. So in order to do what I need, I'd have to call many internal APIs of ansible and I would end up writing ansible's code in my tool.

Answer (score 0):

1. Undefined variable:
   You need execute playbook to understand that the variable wasn't defined.
   For example we have:
   playbook:

   - template: src=foo.j2 dest=/etc/file.conf owner=bin group=wheel mode=0644

foo.j2:
{{e}}

Also you have the [magic variables](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_variables.html): ansible_distribution_release
Sometimes it wasn't defined on host that haven't lsb_release installed

Also you can set variables in runtime -e if you want die on unset variable
Also you can setup variables through inventory!

2. Unused variable
   Depending on environment you can use nothing or you can have when that disable:

   - set_fact:
     vagrant_arch_ext="x86_64"
     when: ansible_architecture == "x86_64"
     tags:

     - vagrant

Also you have default variables.

3. See if vars defined, when case-ignored, are same( conflicting vars
   hereafter)
   Not understand

Comment: We could use dry run for undefined variable but i don't understand how to fit that in picture. I plan to start with something simple and make it more robust with time for cases like magic variables, runtime and other likewise complications. Your apprehensions related to unused variable can be skipped in order to implement a simple solution. Do you have an approach for this? For conflicting vars, example of such group variables could be: myvar, MYVAR ; my_var, MY_VAR. Hope it clarifies.

Comment: Hi, I've been working on my requirement for a while now. [Here](https://github.com/host-anshu/lint-playbook) is the source. Could you please take a look and share your views abt it? TIA.

Comment: Please describe the use case for your tool? And why tools like https://github.com/willthames/ansible-lint https://atom.io/packages/linter-ansible-linting  aren't fit your use cases? And there is discussion that might be interesting for you https://groups.google.com/forum/m/#!msg/ansible-project/AlfMYo5RzIM/LJOWhxgL6G8J